# How do I remove a .html in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc

Hello guys I need help to remove a span after being successful in ajax.
I am inserting a loading when pressing, the save button so that the user does not keep pressing several times and ends up passing the same item several times, but after success it returns without the old way

follows an excerpt from the code where I'm using this function

```js
$('#btn_salvar_consultor').prop("disabled", true);
// Adicionar loading no botão
$('#btn_salvar_consultor').html(
  `<span id="loading_consultor" class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm" role="status" aria-hidden="true"></span>`
);

var Consultor = $('#consultor').val();
var justificativaconsultor = $('#justificativaconsultor').val();

$.ajax({
  url: '@Url.Action("AdicionarConsultor", "Oportunidade")',
  data: {
    id_usuario_responsavel: Consultor,
    id_oportunidade: id_oportunidade,
    justificativaconsultor: justificativaconsultor
  },
  type: 'POST',
  success: function(data) {

    $('#AddConsutlorResponsavel').modal('hide');
    $.ajax({
      url: '@Url.Action("_PartialOportunidadeTimeline", "Oportunidade")',
      data: {
        id_oportunidade: id_oportunidade
      },
      type: 'POST',
      success: function(data) {
        $('#btn_salvar_consultor').prop("disabled", false);
        $('#loading_consultor').remove()
        $('#consultor').val("0");
        $('#justificativaconsultor').val("");
        $("#partinal_container-fluid").html(data);

      }

    });
  },
  error: function(xhr, status, error) {
    swal({
      title: 'Ops!',
      text: error,
      icon: 'error',
      timer: 10000,
      button: 'OK!'
    });
    $('#btn_salvar_consultor').prop("disabled", false);
    $('#loading_consultor').remove();
  }
});
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal fade" id="AddConsutlorResponsavel" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="TituloModalCentralizado" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content" style="box-shadow: 0 0 1em black; border:solid 1px">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="TituloModalCentralizado">Selecione o consultor</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Fechar">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
      </div>
      <div id="partinal_container-fluid" class="modal-body">

        <div class="row">
          <select id="consultor" class="form-control" data-val="true" name="consultor">
            <option value="0">[Selecione...]</option>
            @foreach (var item in ViewBag.Consultor) {
            <option value="@item.UsuarioId">@item.NomeCompleto</option>
            }
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <label class="col-form-label">Justificativa</label>
          <textarea id="justificativaconsultor" class="form-control"></textarea>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btn_salvar_consultor" onclick="AddConsultor()">Salvar</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what is your issue? the "$('#loading_consultor').remove()" doesn't work?

Comment: hello Alex,
It doesn't work, when it removes, it removes the save text and it gets small

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please FIX it to make a [mcve] Now it gives console errors. Also rewrite the question to make sense with the new random comment you added

Comment: Hello mplungjan in fact I had already found the error and fixed it with an update that I put in the question, because I realized that after I did the ajax post and removed the span, the save text was also removed, so I add the text again

Comment: After the editing you did my question got more messy

Comment: Please remove the solution from the question and add it as an answer below!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution

I realized that when I remove the span it removes the text, it follows the correction after success or error in ajax.

```
$('#btn_salvar_consultor').prop("disabled", false).text("Salvar");
```

instead of

```
$('#btn_salvar_consultor').prop("disabled", false);
```